# Importing an FBX file with Animation into Blender

Tags: blender, fbx

I have an FBX file with a Knight character and an Idle Animation defined on it. The Knight Character looks upright in the FBX File as shown below

[image]

When I import the FBX file into Blender, It looks mangled as shown below:

[image]

What settings do I use in Blender for the character to appear upright as in the FBX File?

Both the files could be found at: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7a01b833a6de70eb5733a0824be2d85a20240205130527/5a8a2f

When I view the FBX file in an FBXViewer App Online (like https://overbits.herokuapp.com/fbxgltf/) I am able to see the Knight character with the animation, so I’d want to be able to see the same in Blender too.

[image]

Note: I am using Blender 3.0.0

Thank you.